# The amount changes and is incorrect when I add a second join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I should start off saying I am using postgresql. I have four tables, the customer_orders, payments and clearinghouse_orders. 
Customer_orders is one to many with payments and clearinghouse_orders.

When I use this query I the total of remits is correct:

```
SELECT mailers.mail_date, SUM(cho.remit) AS remits
FROM mailers
RIGHT JOIN customer_orders co
ON mailers.id = co.mailer_id
LEFT JOIN clearinghouse_orders cho
ON co.id = cho.customer_order_id
GROUP BY mailers.mail_date
```

The remit totals are perfect. When I add the payments table the remits increase. I suspect when I add the payments it starts counting some of the remits twice where there are two payment. Here is the code that needs correcting:

```
SELECT mailers.mail_date, SUM(cho.remit) AS remits, SUM(p.payment_amt) AS    payments
FROM mailers
RIGHT JOIN customer_orders co
ON mailers.id = co.mailer_id
LEFT JOIN clearinghouse_orders cho
ON co.id = cho.customer_order_id
LEFT JOIN payments p
ON co.id = p.customer_order_id
GROUP BY mailers.mail_date
```

I am a very early beginner of SQL so please go easy on me. Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desire result. Try creating a small sample on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theory is correct, a simple sub-query to remove duplicate payment rows should fix this...

```
SELECT mailers.mail_date, SUM(cho.remit) AS remits, SUM(p.payment_amt) AS    payments
FROM mailers
RIGHT JOIN customer_orders co
ON mailers.id = co.mailer_id
LEFT JOIN clearinghouse_orders cho
ON co.id = cho.customer_order_id
LEFT JOIN
    (
        select
            customer_order_id,
            sum(payment_amt) as payment_amt
        from
            payments
        group by
            customer_order_id
    ) as p
ON co.id = p.customer_order_id
GROUP BY mailers.mail_date
```